# Normalizing constants for Extreme value distributions

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, random-variables, order-statistics

I have a question regarding the normalizing constants $\mu$ and $\sigma$ that appear in the following problem.

Let the random variable $Y_n$ be $Y_n=max(a_1,a_{2},\cdots, a_n)$ and $X_{n}$ be $X_n=min(a_1,a_{2},\cdots, a_n)$, where $a_i$s are Chi-square random variables with $K$ degrees of freedom. It is well-known in extreme value theory that the CDF of $X_n$ and $Y_n$ converges (in distribution) as follows:

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}~~~Pr\left(\frac{Y_n-\mu}{\sigma}\leq x\right)\rightarrow G_M(x)~~~~~~~~~~(P1)$$

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}~~~Pr\left(\frac{X_n-\mu_{1}}{\sigma_{1}}\leq x\right)\rightarrow G_m(x)~~~~~~~~~~(P2)$$

where $G_M(x)$ and $G_m(x)$ are Gumbel CDFs for maxima and minima respectively and the values of $\mu$ and $\sigma$ can be given explicitly (see for example link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10687-010-0125-3).

My question is: Are the normalizing constants same for both the problem $P1$ and $P2$? I mean, is it true that $\mu=\mu_1$ and $\sigma=\sigma_1$? I could not find the values of $\mu_1$ and $\sigma_1$ in the literature.I will appreciate your answer and possible references.

Comment: Is there a reason why you do not wish to derive the pdf of the max $(Y_n)$ and min $(X_n)$ exactly?

Comment: The pdf max and min of iid random variables for large $n$ may yield a degenerate distribution. Thus, people look for alternate ways to derive the distributions for large $n$. One such a way is to find the convergence of max and min using Fisher-Tippett theorem.

Comment: Makes no sense at all. If the limit distribution is degenerate (i.e. a constant) for infinite $n$, then so be it. In this particular case, the exact solution (a) has a closed-form, and (b) it is easy to derive. Mucking around with approximations does not appear to serve any meaningful purpose in this instance.

Comment: Sorry Mr. wolfies. By degenerate distribution I mean distribution which is not smooth and exhibit a sharp transition from 0 to 1. The distribution takes either 0 or 1. I have the exact solution (distributions) in closed form. However, those distributions degenerate not to a constant.

Answer (score 1):

I am answering my own question above. The correct answer is that $\mu \neq \mu_1$ and $\sigma \neq \sigma_1$. Thus, the normalizing constants for the maximum and minimum extreme value distributions are entirely different.

This is illustrated in the monograph "Extreme Value and Related Models with Applications in Engineering and Science by
Enrique Castillo, Ali S. Hadi, N. Balakrishnan, Jose M. Sarabia". See page no. 203-205.